# Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer in Logstash ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash

I am getting the Logstash errors:

```
[2018-10-10T17:24:11,048][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
[2018-10-10T17:24:11,049][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
[2018-10-10T17:24:11,047][ERROR][logstash.filters.ruby    ] Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

My input:

```
"files": [{
        "SHA256": "1213447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",
        "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",
        "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"
    }, {
        "SHA256": "1213447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",
        "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",
        "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"
    }, {
        "SHA256": "1212447D713ECA24484983E754474D9D2F4A283D77DDBD9C8084CD7AA0574ACF",
        "MD5": "7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC",
        "SHA1": "6026B28C6049115272138AD357A5AF67B99354A5"
    }
]
```

My code:

```
a = event.get("files"); event.set("files_md5", a.map { |e| e["MD5"]
```

The code is doing a transformation of the input above to:

```
"files":["7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC","7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC","7D332F11DD7389C8121AA523F07CFEEC"]
```

No data is being dropped because of those errors, however, I would like not to have them. 
I have tried:

```
a = event.get("files"); event.set("files_md5", a.map { |e| e["MD5"].to_i
```

Is there a way to do the implicit conversion correctly in this case?
Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `event`? What is being shoved into logstash? How do you know, or why do you think, that it's an issue with the `files` value? If you explicitly set `files` to something like `[1, 2, 3]` does the error go away?

Comment: `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` happens when you try to use the subscript operator (square brackets) on an Array (or Integer) and pass a string as an argument. It is likely that in `a.map { |e| e["MD5"] }` there are cases where `e` is not a Hash like you expect. I can't see how that would happen with the info you have provided.

Comment: I believe that the problem is with

 "files": {
      "MD5": "BF61205C5E493491FB43543545396EF0",
      "SHA256": "781E65DAF30170A13054A3AE785A8604EC61910B9B17349B7DBE8F0C6A3D8B24",
      "SHA1": "DB33A474F739EAD56B1BBABD4D4EEA6BF9C62B5E"
    }
that does not have more than one occurence. But I do not understand why is that happening. The event I believe it means in this context read the json element.